# передать двумерный динамический массив в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, сортировка

Мне нужно передать в функцию sort двумерный массив, и в ней сортировать его по алфавиту. Не пойму, как конкретно это записать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>


 int string_count = pow(10,6);
int j;
int i;

void sort(char &pMassive) {
    char reserve[11];
    for (j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (i = string_count - 1; i > j; i--) {
         std::cout<< pMassive[i]<< std::endl;

            if (strcmp(pMassive[i - 1], pMassive[i]) > 0) {
                strcpy(reserve, pMassive[i]);
                strcpy(pMassive[i], pMassive[i - 1]);
                strcpy(pMassive[i - 1], reserve);
            }
        }
        std::cout << j << " sorted " << pMassive[j] << std::endl;

    }
}


int main() {

char **pMassive = new char*[string_count];
for (i = 0; i < string_count; i++) pMassive[i] = new char[11];
    char symbols[27]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    for (j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pMassive[j][i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
            
        }
         std::cout<< pMassive[j]<< std::endl;
    }
    
        // std::cout<< pMassive<< std::endl;

    //  sort(*pMassive);
    
for (i = 0; i < string_count; i++) delete[] pMassive[i];

delete[]pMassive;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и передавать —

```
void sort(char ** pMassive)
```

Другое дело, что теперь, когда у вас *массив указателей*, вам не надо копировать строки — достаточно менять указатели.

Там еще несколько огрехов у вас есть — словом, вот исправленный код, сами сравните, что я исправил, и постарайтесь разобраться, *почему*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>


int string_count = 20; //pow(10,6);
int j;
int i;

void sort(char **pMassive) {
    char *reserve;
    for (j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (i = string_count - 1; i > j; i--) {
            //std::cout<< pMassive[i]<< std::endl;

            if (strcmp(pMassive[i - 1], pMassive[i]) > 0) {
                reserve = pMassive[i];
                pMassive[i] = pMassive[i - 1];
                pMassive[i - 1] = reserve;
            }
        }
        std::cout << j << " sorted " << pMassive[j] << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {

    char **pMassive = new char*[string_count];
    for (i = 0; i < string_count; i++) pMassive[i] = new char[11] {0};
    char symbols[27]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pMassive[j][i] = symbols[rand() % 26];

        }
        std::cout<< "unsorted  " << pMassive[j]<< std::endl;
    }

    // std::cout<< pMassive<< std::endl;

    sort(pMassive);

    for (i = 0; i < string_count; i++) delete[] pMassive[i];

    delete[]pMassive;

    return 0;
}
```